# Truncated random variables

Tags: probability-theory

**Problem** : Let $ \{ Y_n : n \geq 1 \}$ be sequence of mutually independent identically distributed random variables satisfying $E[ \left | Y_1 \right |] \le \infty$. $X_n=\sum_{m=1}^n Y_m$ for $n \geq 1$. Then, for every $R > 0$ show that:
$$ E[\left | X_n/n \right |] \leq R/n^{1/2} + 2E[|Y_1|,|Y_1|\geq R] $$

**What i have done** : 
 I truncated the r.v's $Y_n$ and $X_n$ as follows: 
$Y_n^{(R)}=Y_n1_{|Y_n|<R} - E[Y_n,|Y_n|<R]$ and $X_n^{(R)}= \sum_{m=1}^nY_n^{(R)}$ then I showed:

$ E\left [\left | \frac{X_n}{n} \right |\right ] \leq E\left [\left | \frac{X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ] + E\left [\left | \frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ] $

$\leq \sqrt{E\left [\left ( \frac{X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right )^2\right ]} + E\left [\left | \frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ]=
\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{E\left [\left ( X_n^{(R)} \right )^2\right ]} + E\left [\left | \frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ]$
$=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{E\left [ \sum_{m=1}^n (Y_m^{(R)})^2 \right ]} + E\left [\left | \frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ] = 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}E\left [ (Y_1^{(R)})^2 \right ]} + E\left [\left | \frac{X_n-X_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ]$
$=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}E\left [ (Y_1^{(R)})^2 \right ]} + 
E\left [\left | \frac{\sum_{m=1}^n Y_n-Y_n^{(R)}}{n} \right |\right ] \leq
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}E\left [ (Y_1^{(R)})^2 \right ]} + 
E\left [ \frac{  \sum_{m=1}^n \left | Y_n-Y_n^{(R)}\right |}{n} \right ]$
$\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}E\left [ (Y_1^{(R)})^2 \right ]} + 
E\left [ \left | Y_1-Y_1^{(R)}\right | \right ]$

**Trouble** : I couldnt show,

1. $E[ (Y_1^{(R)})^2] \leq R^2$
2. $E\left [ \left | Y_1-Y_1^{(R)}\right | \right ] \leq 2E[|Y_1|,|Y_1|\geq R]$

I guess I am in the right track but I am not sure. Could you please help me to complete my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Notice that 
   $$\mathbb E[(Y_1^{(R)})^2]=\mathbb E[Y_1^2\chi_{|Y_1|\leqslant R}]-\mathbb E[Y_1\chi_{|Y_1|\leqslant R}]^2\leqslant R^2$$
   because $\mathbb E[Y_1\chi_{|Y_1|\leqslant R}]^2\geqslant 0$.
2. Since $$Y_1-Y_1^{(R)}=Y_1\chi_{|Y_1|\gt R}-\mathbb E[Y_1\chi_{|Y_1|\gt R}],$$
   we have 
   $$|Y_1-Y_1^{(R)}|\leqslant |Y_1|\chi_{|Y_1|\gt R}+\mathbb E[|Y_1|\chi_{|Y_1|\gt R}]$$
   and we conclude taking expectation.

Comment: but isn't $Y_1-Y_1^{(R)}=Y_1 \chi_{|Y_1|\geq R}+E[Y_1 \chi_{|Y_1|< R}]$ ? Are you assuming $E[Y_1]=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise we wouldn't have the convergence to $0$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I totally missed that part. Thanks alot

Comment: You are welcome.